# Sort php array by multipule values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sort this array by the date but the array is merged and has two different types of date.

```
[0] => Object
        [Something] => hey
        [date]=>2010-01-03
[1] => Object
        [something] => heyagain
        [somethingelse] => heythere
        [posted_date] => 2011-08-22
```

I want this array to sort the whole array by date and posted date but the array comes out in order as:

```
Array1=>(date1,date2,date3) Array2=>(date1,date2,date3)
```

For instance in (Array2,date2) may be before (Array1,date1) but it does not sort that way. I want to see

```
Output=>Array2(date1),Array2(date2),Array1(date1),Array2(date3),Array1(date2),Array1(date3
```

I have tried  `array_multisort($merge, SORT_NUMERIC, $arg, 'posted_date', SORT_DESC, 'date', SORT_DESC)` and a few other but I can't get it to work. I hope this isn't confusing anyone.

Comment: I'd look at `array_walk()` and `array_map()`

Answer (score 1):

To use `array_multisort`, you need to create multiple arrays first, e.g. accessing properties that you want to sort over and wrapping those into another array.

The [manual page](http://php.net/array_multisort) gives good examples how to do this or that. However strings just won't work:

```
array_multisort($merge, SORT_NUMERIC, $arg, 'posted_date', SORT_DESC, 'date', SORT_DESC);
```

See as well: [Sort data of Php array by values of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363036/sort-data-of-php-array-by-values-of-another-array)

Comment: Multisort will sort the arrays how i like them but my outcome is still in order starting with Array1 then on to Array2. They have to be in the same array and then sorted to mix them but order by date.

Comment: `[0] => Object` has no `posted_date`, `[1] => Object` has no `date`. I wonder if you want to sort in this case, you dropped that part in your question.

Comment: [0]=>Object does not have a posted date. Array1 had 'posted_date' and Array2 has 'date'. These were merged so it has different key names for dates. I tried selecting the 'posted_date' AS 'date' from the db but zend wouldn't have it or most likely my error.